# statcktrace of classmethod not getting printed in python

Tags: python, static-methods, stack-trace, class-method

There is a @classmethod in a class which is being called automatically when class is imported. I want to know the parameters being passed to that method. So I deliberately added a code to crash that function and to print the stacktrace. However, it is not printing who is calling this load method.

I actually want to know who is sending values of parameters (Specifically **cuda_device**)

```
 @classmethod
    def load(cls,
             config: Params,
             serialization_dir: str,
             weights_file: str = None,
             cuda_device: int = -1) -> 'Model':

        who called me?   #line added by me to crash and print stacktrace
```

```
  File "/data/TFS/AI%20-%20Projects/MULTI_PROC/allen_ws/urls.py", line 19, in <module>
    from allen_ws import ANLP_API_SB1
  File "/data/TFS/AI%20-%20Projects/MULTI_PROC/allen_ws/ANLP_API_SB1.py", line 5, in <module>
    from allennlp.predictors.predictor import Predictor
  File "/anaconda3/envs/allennlpenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/allennlp/predictors/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from allennlp.predictors.predictor import Predictor
  File "/anaconda3/envs/allennlpenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/allennlp/predictors/predictor.py", line 8, in <module>
    from allennlp.models import Model
  File "/anaconda3/envs/allennlpenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/allennlp/models/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from allennlp.models.model import Model
  File "/anaconda3/envs/allennlpenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/allennlp/models/model.py", line 331
    who called me?
```

In above stack trace models/__ init __ .py is calling the model.py line 331 (at line 331 I added "who called me"), the content of models/__ init __ .py at line 6 following is written:

```
from allennlp.models.model import Model
```

This is also not calling _load method with any parameters.
Suggestions please, how can I find who is passing cuda_device parameter value to load function?

Comment: would help to have more of the error, but I guess this is a syntax error hence it's thrown when the file is parsed/imported the first time.   `assert False, "who called me"` might be better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have introduced a *syntax error* into your code. That means your class cannot be imported, let alone run.

If you want to see a runtime stack trace then introduce a runtime error, not a syntax error.

```
a = 1 / 0
```

should do it.

Comment: Or even better raise a simple error: `raise ValueError()`.